# Are the dual boot issues with Windows 10 Anniversary resolved?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

About one month ago, it was in the news that some dual-boot users [found their Linux partition deleted](https://linux.slashdot.org/story/16/08/03/1614223/windows-10-anniversary-update-borks-dual-boot-partitions) after upgrading to Windows 10 anniversary.

I have a Windows partition that I haven't touched since then (for other reasons); is it considered safe to update now, or should I leave it in the freezer for a while again?

Comment: You will have to ask Microsoft about this. This is not something related to Ubuntu.

Comment: @edwinksl I 1/2 agree with you. I think this is still on-topic here. I mean, for crying out loud, we have a Q&A on this site for how to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on... I think we can let this question slide.

Comment: @edwinksl I understand that technically this is a Windows bug, but I thought dual boot issues were on-topic here. There are [9.560 questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/dual-boot) tagged dual-boot here, at least.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni - I think you meant 9,560 instead of 9.560 :)

Comment: @AndroidDev No problem, feel free to disagree. Even though this is a dual-boot problem, it is specifically caused by a Windows bug that can't be fixed from Ubuntu's end. This is in contrast to, say, Windows messing up GRUB on a dual-boot system that can actually be fixed from Ubuntu's end.

Comment: @edwinksl Regarding the controversy taking place here:  I bet that AskUbuntu (and SE sites generally) ranks higher in the search results than any Windows-centered forum.

Comment: @CristianaNicolae Sure, this question is better suited for Super User then. We all are trying to help OP get answers, which he/she will probably not get in Ask Ubuntu because there is close to nothing we can do for this particular problem while Windows users on Super User may actually have some ideas.

Comment: @edwinksl Well, in that case, maybe it should be flagged as off-topic on AskUbuntu and moved where it belongs, on SuperUser...

Comment: @CristianaNicolae You are welcome to make an informed decision and flag as you deem appropriate. I have already voted to close this as off-topic.

Comment: @edwinksl I have flagged it. By default, I have flagged it to be closed, as there is no option to flag it to be migrated.

Comment: I was installing a fresh copy of the anniversary update and then allocated space for 16.04.1. After installing it and reboot, it went back to Windows without the Grub screen. Did the grub fix and what not, still boots directly into Windows. Wasted a good 3 hours tinkering. Guess I've to go back to VM :(

Comment: @CristianaNicolae There is an option to flag for "moderation attention", which I believe is more appropriate in these cases, as flags for closure could trigger spam warnings. In any case, I have no objection to migration to Super User, if that is the consensus.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Thank you! I have changed my flag!

Comment: @FedericoPoloni From what I can see, there is no consensus yet. You are more than welcome to keep the post here if you are convinced this is the best place to get answers.

Comment: I was asked if this was a good fit for superuser. While I wouldn't modhammer it, the question seems *hugely* speculative over whether this is an issue - its linking a slashdot post linking omgubuntu, citing a person who heard of people who lost data. I'm disinclined to support a move to SU - while it feels borderline unclear. The major windows 10 updates are essentially an OS reinstall/upgrade in place, and one really ought to back up the entire drive(s) before doing this.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek This is not exact: the omgubuntu page contains links to twitter posts of two users that experienced the issue **first-hand**, in addition to one with a  second-hand report ("seen multiple reports of...", though this one from a Canonical community manager). So I disagree with the "hugely speculative" part.

Answer (score 1):

The Anniversary Update for Windows 10 recently installed on my development machine and the dual-boot grub menu still loaded both Linux and Win 10.  I suspect that some users have seen the MBR over-written by Windows rather than their Linux partition actually being deleted, so that all that was likely required was to re-install grub.  After all, Windows says it can't "see" Linux partitions; they are just some hole in the disk as far as Redmond is concerned! {grin}

Comment: The notorious Windows Anniversary Update **can** do two nasties. It can overwrite GRUB with a standard Windows Boot Manager. And, there **have** been instances of it turning Ubuntu/Linux partitions into **UNALLOCATED** space! Ouch. Cheers, Al

Comment: Windows can be so jealous!

Answer (score 0):

I just updated three dual-boot machines, two UEFI/gpt partitioned, and one legacy/MSDOS partitioned by downloading the Windows anniversary 10 update ISO and running it locally.  All three updates proceeded without problems, no Ubuntu partitions were touched, and the grub bootloaders were not affected.  That said, backups are still a  really good idea -- bad things have been reported by others.